# Parse cron expression in Quartz.Net

Tags: c#, .net, cron, quartz.net

I have one problem which refers to quartz.net cron expressions. I have read many articles and tried many pieces of code but without any results, so I feel little bit hopeless and that's why I decided to ask You. Maybe somebody also had similar problem. 
Is any way to parse cron expression for Quartz.Net to DateTime format?
For example I have a cron:

```
var cron = new Quartz.CronExpression("0 * 8-22 * * ?");
```

I have tried use GetFinalFireTime() GetTimeAfter() GetNextValidTimeAfter() but application still throws exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred. Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

Here is my code:

```
CronExpression cron = new Quartz.CronExpression("0 * 8-22 * * ?");
DateTimeOffset? nextFire = cron.GetNextValidTimeAfter(dt);
```

I also will be very thankful if you can tell me if is there any cron parser library which allows to create crons easy. Something similar to cronMaker.com but proper working with Quartz.Net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetFinalFireTime` hasn't been [implemented yet](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/master/src/Quartz/CronExpression.cs#L2068).
`GetNextValidTimeAfter` should be working if you're using one of the latest versions.

If you want to generate **cron expressions** in c# you can use `CronScheduleBuilder`.

**UPDATE:**

You can find a simple project [here](https://skydrive.live.com/embed?cid=669ADF1AF64DF389&resid=669ADF1AF64DF389!243&authkey=ABHuyLgcMnVj-Mw) (QuartzNetCronExpressions.zip) where you can see how it works.

*NOTE: I've used VS 2013, Framework 4.5.1 and Quartz.net 2.2.1 (nuget package).*

Comment: Hi,
Thank You for quick reply. I am using quartz version 2.2.1 and it is latest version but still do something wrong because application throws the same (System.AccessViolationException) exception when I try use GetNextValidTimeAfter(). Have You got any idea what may be wrong? I am really desperated and I will be very thankfull for answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer where you can find a simple example. It must work. Give us some feedback.

Comment: Hi LeftyX, Thank You VERY much for help. Your application works fine. I think that I have some problems with my machine because my project does not throw errors on other machines... How You think, I going to create WindowsFormApplication which should looks like www.cronmaker.com, is better to use numericTextBoxes, calendars and build expresion using expresions (0 * 8-22 * * ?) or using CronScheduleBuilder? thanks once again for Your help. Best regards

Comment: Glad you've managed to sort things out. I don't know if you'll be able to create all the expressions you want with CronScheduleBuilder but you can give it a go. Cheers.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for late answer. I figure out what is the reason. It throws this error only on KVM machine in DEGUG mode, when I check code lines step by step. I suppose that it is problem with virtual machine not in quartz or .net. Many thanks for Your help !

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this same problem.Somehow my project configuration for build was set x86. It was not giving me option to change it.I unloaded project and changed it in notepad.Build configuration was set as "AnyCPU" and things started working Problem Solved